# Robolectric 3.4 meta-data mocking not working on API 26

Tags: android, robolectric

I am trying to get some tests running in this open source project after upgrading to API 26 and Robolectric 3.4.2 (from 3.3 due to 3.3 not supporting API 26)

It seems that the mocking of metadata doesn't work anymore.

The setup is as follows

`Bundle metaData = mock(Bundle.class);
RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationInfo().metaData = metaData;`

However when the unit test is run, the metaData returns as `null`

`Context applicationContext = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext();
ApplicationInfo info = applicationContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
Bundle metaData = info.metaData;`

And I cannot understand why. I am new to Robolectric and Mockito, but I'd really like to figure out what is wrong and how to fix it, so any pointers are really appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to test?

Comment: I was trying to run the tests for the SDK for Parse for Android. I fixed it at last by compiling against API 26, using Robolectric 3.3.2 which is the last 3.3 version to support API 26 and setting sdk = 25 in the robolectric config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the tests to run at last by compiling against API 26, but using Robolectric 3.3.2 which is the last 3.3 version that still supports API 26. Then in the robolectric config I set sdk = 25.

I'm just adding this here in case it helps anybody else. I cannot figure out why it doesn't work with robolectric 3.4.